# C++ how to get the name of a argument passed to a function (an STL iterator)

Tags: c++

have a function below called `relu()`:

```
void mModelRecorder::relu(Data::TensorIterator inputTensor){}
```

which I call like this:

`rc.relu(conv);`

Inside relu I want to get the name of the argument inputTensor (as a string) that was passed in.

In this case it is "conv".

My question is how could I do this.

I'm just learning about function templates and iterators so I don't really understand what inputTensor is.

Here is the definition of `TensorIterator`.

Comment: You can't, and neither should you want to.

Comment: If the name of an object matters to the code, then the name should be part of the object, usually as a member of type `std::string`.

Comment: Change function signature to accept another string parameter: `relu(Data::TensorIterator inputTensor, char const * const psz_name); rc.relu(conv, "conv");` Note that C++ has only few reflection routines and automatic extraction of variable name is currently not supported.

Comment: What do you need this for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You COULD do this with a macro - but you really don't want to

Comment: In your code you have a map with a std::string as key. Just to be clear, it's not this string your looking for, but the actual name of the parameter? In this case you probably need to change your design slightly. This would be trivial in a language like python but in C++ it's not really possible and there are most likely many other (better) ways to achieve the same thing in a different way.

Comment: The name of the argument is (trivially) "inputTensor", and the argument is a different object from the one whose value you passed in. Also, there can be zero or more names that refer to the same thing. In `TensorIterator a; TensorIterator & b = a; relu(a); relu(b);`, "a" and "b" are synonyms; `relu(a)` and `relu(b)` are equivalent. In `relu(TensorIterator());`, there is no name at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible under the current version of the C++ standard (C++17). There are proposals for Reflection in C++20, but I'm not very familiar with them, and I honestly severely doubt that any of them would cover this case, as it seems very convoluted and unusual.

If you want to pass some kind of information depending on where you pass the object from, the proper thing would be to store this additional information inside the object itself.

Comment: `#define call(X) rc.relu(X, #X)`  looks possible to me - with a change of signature of relu

Comment: But this is happening at the caller side, which I would argue is more or less the same as just storing the relevant information inside the object being passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the name as a string argument:

```
void mModelRecorder::relu(Data::TensorIterator inputTensor, const char *name_of_arg);

rc.relu(conv, "conv");
```

If you would like to avoid duplicating the name, you could use macro trickery:

```
#define REFLECT_PASSED_ARG_NAME(arg) (arg), #arg

rc.relu(REFLECT_PASSED_ARG_NAME(conv));
```

However, while this removes duplication, it arguably reduces readability. The call *looks* like only one argument is passed, while in reality, the macro expands into two arguments. This can be highly confusing.

---

Furthermore, I recommend reconsidering **why** you would like to know the name of the variable within `relu`. If the behaviour of the function relies on such detail, you probably should re-design.

For example, if you simply want to give a name for a tensor iterator, then conflating the name of the iterator, and the name of the variable is a very bad idea. Instead, you could create an object, with members `name` and `iterator`, and store the name in that member. Example:

```
struct named_tensor_iterator {
    std::string name;
    Data::TensorIterator iterator;
};

// pass by reference to avoid copying the name
void mModelRecorder::relu(const named_tensor_iterator& inputTensor);

named_tensor_iterator input {
     "fancy iterator",
     conv,
};
rc.relu(input);
```